# Disabling Spree Inventory tracking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I have a problem with spree inventory. I have disabled it by `track_inventory_levels` option. But records still appears in `spree_inventory_units` table. It's normal? I have many units on order (about 1000-10000) and it is problem.

Comment: which version of spree you are using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for question [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spree-user/AOw-LEH5uN4):

```
private

def update_inventory; end
```